# Best way to process non-standard quotes in XML parser

Tags: c#, regex, xml-parsing, quote

I am creating a program that process text with XML formatting. I found that when the tag values are non-ASCII quotes (double quotes / ASCII 34, single quote / ASCII 39) the parsing throws exception. Such quotes may come from editing software such as Ms Word (automatic formatting).

Currently I parses each line of my text box and replace the quotes before processing the XML. Here is the code (in C#)

```
int nLines = textBox1.Lines.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < nLines; i++)
{
    // get the current line and replace quotes with standard ones
    line = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Lines[i], "[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]", "'");
    line = Regex.Replace(line, "[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]", "\"");
```

I wonder if there is a better / more correct / faster way to achieve this? What I mean by a more correct way is such the method shall covers almost all possibilities of quotes (I heard that \d can be used for 0-9 as well as unicode). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\p{Pi}` and `\p{Pf}` classes can be useful to match this kind of quotes. However they don't make the difference between single and double quotes.

`\p{Pi}` -> opening quotes

`\p{Pf}` -> closing quotes